# Trouble with ImageDownloadService

Tags: codenameone

Earlier I was using the static `createImageToStorage()` method and it was working fine, but I wasn't able to get the scaling the way I wanted so I decided to create an instance of the class and use the non-static methods.  Here's my code:

```
Label myLabel = findMyLabel();
ImageDownloadService imgService = new ImageDownloadService(URL_PREFIX+"images/"+picPath, myLabel);
imgService.setDownloadToStyles(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(imgService);
```

The picture doesn't load, and when I debugged the `InputStream` provided by `ReadResponse()` had no data.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be set to the `bgImage` of the style because of the `setDownloadToStyles`. I would recommend you use `URLImage` which is better designed with regard to scaling behavior.